# I get an error when trying to change the value in the for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an application in Spring Boot. 
But I got stuck in Java loops. Why does it make such a mistake. 
This error occurs even though I have not made any settings for the ArrayList.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Here my code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String Update(@RequestParam(value = "this") int updateId,Model model,String newName,String newSurname,String newCountry) {
        model.addAttribute("id",updateId);
        model.addAttribute("name",personList.get(updateId).getName());
        model.addAttribute("surname",personList.get(updateId).getSurname());
        model.addAttribute("country",personList.get(updateId).getCountry());
        for (Person person : personList) {
            System.out.println(personList.size());
            if (person.getId()==updateId) {
                if (null!=newName) {
                    person.setName(newName);
                    updateControl+=1;
                    System.out.println(personList.size());
                }
                if (null!=newSurname) {
                    updateControl+=1;
                    person.setSurname(newSurname);
                }
                if (null!=newCountry) {
                    person.setCountry(newCountry);
                    updateControl+=1;
                }
            }

        }
        if (updateControl==0) {
            return "update";
        }
        else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Here my error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: can you add the parts where you fill and instantiate the ArrayList to your post?

Comment: where did the " personList "  is coming from ?

Comment: that error means you are trying to get the first element of an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `personList` is empty then you can't call `personList.get()` on it.
You should check if the index `updateId` is smaller than the `personList` size.

```
@RequestMapping("/update")
public String Update(@RequestParam(value = "this") int updateId,Model model,String newName,String newSurname,String newCountry) {
    model.addAttribute("id",updateId);
    if (updateId < personList.size()) {
        model.addAttribute("name",personList.get(updateId).getName());
        model.addAttribute("surname",personList.get(updateId).getSurname());
        model.addAttribute("country",personList.get(updateId).getCountry());
    // ...
}
```

What I also often like to do is to use a guard clause:

```
@RequestMapping("/update")
public String Update(@RequestParam(value = "this") int updateId,Model model,String newName,String newSurname,String newCountry) {
    model.addAttribute("id",updateId);
    if (updateId >= personList.size()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }
    // ...
```

Maybe you also don't properly initialize or load the personList if you are sure that the element with index `updateId` should definitely be there.

Answer (score 0):

Error shows, there is no data in the list.
But you try to get data from empty list.

```
model.addAttribute("name",personList.get(updateId).getName());
model.addAttribute("surname",personList.get(updateId).getSurname());
model.addAttribute("country",personList.get(updateId).getCountry());
```

Please check your  `personList`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly shows, you are accessing `Index: 0` element from list of  `Size: 0`. 
You can add null check at beginning to avoid this,

```
if (null != personList && ! personList.isEmpty()) {
    //rest of code
}
```